# CSS outline property for inline elements in Firefox different than Chrome/Safari. Javascript solution?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, svg

I'm trying to draw a line around a multi-line, `display:inline` text – kind of like setting a stroke to a union of DOM rects created.

Seemed like CSS `outline` would do but behaves inconsistently across browsers.

See code below, using Chrome/Safari and Firefox:

```css
body { 
  font-family: sans-serif; 
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 50px;
}
section {
  width: 200px;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  display:inline;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  outline-offset: 10px;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Some random text here and there</h2>
</section>
```

FF just does not draw the lines the same way as other browsers. Is there a way to make this work cross-browser?

[In Safari/Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRdbH.png)

[In FF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o1wT.png)

If not, is there a way to achieve same effect, using some combination of JS, SVG, or, or...

Comment: Try raising a [bug in bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=Layout%3A+Text+and+Fonts)

Comment: @RobertLongson Just did it [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1564896). Raising it does not fulfill my immediate needs though sadly...